# UHF RFID Reader and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, rfid

I‘m looking for a UHF RFID Reader, that can be easily controlled with a raspberry pi and a python3 library. I could only find readers that were for arduino or serial.

Comment: raspberry have the I2C and serial interface, also have library to interfacing it with python.

Comment: I worked with RFID and Raspberry long time ago. Check here if you find anything useful. It was specifically for MIFARE chips https://desfire.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly all RFID readers work on serial communication. So you can easily use any serial port python library to connect to RFID module and get the RFID tag id. This will work on any type of machine i.e. `windows`, `linux` or `raspberry pi`.

For ex, follow below code:

```
import serial

rfid_serial_port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)

id_num = []
i = 0
while True:
    serial_data = self.rfid_serial_port.read()
    data = serial_data.decode('utf-8')
    i = i + 1
    if i == 12:
        i = 0
        ID = "".join(map(str, id_num))
        print(ID)
    else:
        id_num.append(data)
```

Or you can use `pyembedded` python library

`pip install pyembedded`

```
from pyembedded.rfid_module.rfid import RFID
rfid = RFID(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baud_rate=9600)
print(rfid.get_id())
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyembedded/

Comment: This package looks good, can I control the frequency?